# numpy.array with and without specifying dtype behaves strange

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am completely puzzled by this.

From the following

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([4, -9])
a[0] = 0.4
a
```

I **expected output:** `array([ 0.4, -9])`. But it gives me

`array([ 0, -9])`.

But when I changed the `dtype` to `f`

```
a = np.array([4, -9], 'f')
a[0] = 0.4
a
```

It gives me the expected out put of `array([ 0.40000001, -9.        ], dtype=float32)`

The documentation for `numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)` says:

> dtype : data-type, optional
>   The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

When I initialized the array it initialized the values to `integers` and so when I indexed the array with a `float` it only recognized the `integer` part of `0.4` and hence gave me `0`. This is how I understand it. Is this correct?. But I am still surprised by this behavior.

**Question**: What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your array is of `dtype=np.int64`:

```
In [141]: a = np.array([4, -9])

In [142]: a.dtype
Out[142]: dtype('int64')
```

This means that you can only store integers, and any floats are truncated before assignment is done. If you want to store floats and ints together, you should specify `dtype=object` first:

```
In [143]: a = np.array([4, -9], dtype=object)

In [144]: a[0] = 0.4

In [145]: a
Out[145]: array([0.4, -9], dtype=object)
```

As for the issue with `array([ 0.40000001, -9.        ]`, `0.4`, as a floating point number does not have an exact representation in memory (only an approximate one), which accounts for the imprecision you see.

Comment: Excellent. This solves the problem. Obviously, I have a lot to learn.

Comment: I don't like the idea of using `dtype=object` to save both floats and integers.  It's fine for mixing strings and numbers if needed, or better for holding things like lists.  But for purely numeric data, it's better to use a numeric dtype.

Comment: @hpaulj Accepted. With a non-numeric type you lose out on all the vectorisation benefits.

Comment: What would be a numeric `dtype`  that will do the job?. `float`? `d?`?

Comment: @JackDawkins I think the overarching problem is the fact that you want to store ints and floats together. If you want to do it, this is how. But the advice we give you is this: Don't do it.

Comment: You mean I should store them as for example `[4.0, 9.0]` as opposed to `[4, 9]`?. I am coding up something to numerically check the validity of an analytic Jacobian. Initial data are integers but then step sizes are stuff like `1e-6` etc.

Comment: @JackDawkins Either [4, 9] or [4.0, 9.0]. But not half n half.

Comment: Ah okay. got it.